# How do I use JSON.generator to generate an unnamed array?

Tags: apex

I'm trying to generate:

> `"[{"hello" : "world"}]"`

```
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeArrayStart();
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeStringFeild('hello', 'world');
gen.writeEndObject();
gen.writeArrayEnd();
gen.writeEndObject();
```

Throws the error:
`System.JSONException: Can not start an array, expecting field name`

But the array in my example does not have a field name?

Answer (score 5):

Right now, you open an object before opening your array. An object *must* consist of field value pairs. Here is an annotated version of what you wrote above, with your three typos corrected.

```
gen.writeStartObject();
// output: {
// remove this line

gen.writeStartArray();
// output: [
// your post had a typo here which I have fixed
// using writeStartArray rather than writeArrayStart

gen.writeStartObject();
// output: {

gen.writeStringField('hello', 'world');
// output: "hello": "world"
// your post had a typo here which I have fixed
// using writeStringField rather than writeStringFeild

gen.writeEndObject();
// output: }

gen.writeEndArray();
// output: ]
// your post had a typo here which I have fixed
// using writeEndArray rather than writeArrayEnd

gen.writeEndObject();
// output: }
// remove this line
```

Please note that `JSONGenerator` is almost *never* the correct choice for the job. It is almost universally simpler, easier to read, and better performance to just use out of the box serialization/deserialization. For example, here you could write just one line:

```
String payload = JSON.serialize(new List<Object> {
    new Map<String, String> { 'hello' => 'world' }
});
```

Comment: Also its `writeStartArray` and `writeEndArray`

Comment: Thank you Adrian!

Comment: @muchavie If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Comment: I already upvoted it.   I don't know why it didn't turn green.

Comment: Upvoting and accepting are completely different mechanisms. You have to click the little checkmark next to the answer to indicate that it has solved your problem.